# How to maintain the background color of parent division in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am making a web page (code below the question). In that I have a main division whose width is 90% and whose background color is white. In this division again I have made 4 divisions where in the division is split in 4 equal quadrants. I am hoping to get white color as the background for all these divisions however they are taking the `bgcolor` attribute of body tag. How do I get these divisions to have the same background as that of their parent div?

Code:

```
<body bgcolor="grey">
<div  style="width: 90%;  margin:0 auto; text-align:justify;  background-color: white;" >
    <div id="div1" align="center" style="width: 50%; height: 50%; float: left; background-color: white;">
        <h3> This Division </h3>
        <h4>With separate bg attr</h4>
        <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> C </td>
            <td> 756 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D</td>
            <td>749</td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td onclick="display('test');">E</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="div2" style="width: 50%; height: 50%; float: left;"> This is division 2</div>
    <div id="div3" style="width: 50%; height: 50%; float: left;">This is division 3 </div>
    <div id="div4" style="width: 50%; height: 50%; float: left;">This is division 4</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hello, i used your code and its seems it works as u need. They sub division in the first main division are white and they are not taking the grey color .. check this --> http://prntscr.com/8wkmih     
I guess u need to do ctrl + f5 in chrome to clean your cache and force the page to reload again.

Comment: Hi @Elie.M that is because I have given it white color separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are using Float:left for your child Div
and no floating for parent div that's why Parent div is not filling the area

just add float:left to parent div then it will work as you want

```
<div  style="width: 90%;  margin:0 auto; text-align:justify;  background-color: white;float;left" >
```

Comment: Thanks Viru sirji, but issue is I need my parent division to be center aligned. While your solution worked, I can not apply it to my page.. Any workaround?

Comment: add these four style position: relative;float: left;
margin-left: 50%;
left: -45%;

Comment: it will float your div to left,then set its left position to -45% which is half of its width then set its left margin to 50%, so it will be center of screen for all resolutions

Comment: Thank you Viru bhai! Worked Perfectly!